# $\operatorname{span}(S) = V$, finite dimensional. Does there exist a subset of $S$ which is a basis for $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $S \subset V$ a subset (possibly
infinite) with $\operatorname{span}(S) = V$. Does there exist a subset of $S$ that is a basis for $V$?

Comment: Yes, but in the most general case we need the Axiom of Choice to prove this. In fact, the most general case is *equivalent* to AC.

Comment: I don't think you need AC here as $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: AC is Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Just as an aside, what kind of intuition should I presumably have when I read "linearly independent" in a general context. I mean, other than the definition; that is, what inherent properties should be running through my brain?

Comment: @DonAntonio: You are correct that in the general case of *any* vector space the axiom of choice is needed; but for finite dimensional spaces you don't need any version of the axiom of choice.

Comment: Can those voting to close please explain to the OP *why* they consider this question "not constructive"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Choose $v_1 \in S$, $v_1 \neq 0$. Then $\{v_1\}$ is a linearly independent set. If it spans $V$, it is a basis. If not, choose $v_2 \in S\setminus\operatorname{span}\{v_1\}$. Then $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a linearly independent set. If it spans $V$, it is a basis. If not, choose $v_3 \in S\setminus\operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2\}$, and so on.

That is, suppose $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\} \subseteq S$ is a linearly independent set which does not span $V$. Then for any $v_{k+1} \in S\setminus\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$, you can show (and you should) that $\{v_1, \dots, v_k, v_{k+1}\}$ is a linearly independent set. Note, as $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ does not span $V$, $S\setminus\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ is non-empty (again, you should check this). So given a linearly independent subset of $S$ which does not span $V$, you can always add another vector while maintaining linear independence. As $S$ spans $V$ and $V$ is finite dimensional, this process will eventually terminate (i.e. you will eventually arrive at a set $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\} \subseteq S$ which is linearly independent and spans $V$).

---

**Added Later:** It is worth noting that the above process terminates because $V$ is finite dimensional. If $V$ were infinite dimensional, the process wouldn't terminate. In general, you need Zorn's Lemma to obtain a basis for an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Yes, but how does the infinite-dimensional aspect incorporate here?

Comment: There is no infinite *dimensional* aspect here. $S$ may be infinite in cardinality (i.e. how many vectors it has as elements), but $V$ is only finite dimensional.

Comment: I'm just saying that your "you will eventually arrive at a set $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}\subseteq S$ remark seemed not to capture this aspect.

Comment: There is no aspect to be captured. The fact that $S$ is potentially infinite is irrelevant. As $S$ spans $V$ and $V$ is finite dimensional, the process will terminate after a finite number of steps and you will be left with a basis.

Comment: That's right, the cardinality of a finite set can't exceed the cardinality of a subspace contained in it. So this side comment is erroneous then, yes?

Comment: If you are dealing with real or complex vector spaces, the only subspace contained in a finite set is $\{0\}$. I'm not sure which side comment you are referring to.

Comment: I meant the "possibly infinite" comment. It is erroneous.

Comment: Correct?1234567

Comment: Erronous means it is incorrect, which it is not. $S$ *could* be infinite, the point is that it doesn't matter, all that you need to know about $S$ is that it spans $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $B$ to be a maximal linearly independent subset of $S$. Then $B$ is finite because $V$ is finite dimensional. Also $B$ spans $V$ because every $s\in S\setminus B$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$ since $B\cup \{s\}$ cannot be linearly independent due to the maximality of $B$.

Comment: What do you mean "maximal linearly independent set," just to be clear?

Comment: @Trancot, a set that is linearly independent and such that no strict superset is linearly independent.